# Concatenating inside for loop

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I am trying to create folders inside another folder using numbers. The code is below. Now I am checking with echo. But it is printing empty string.What is the mistake in it ? and how to achieve this?

```
    set folder=d:/delete_It
    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION        
    FOR /L %%r IN (72,1,98) DO (
    REM mkdir %%r
    if not errorlevel 0 goto somethingbad
    set final_Dir=%folder%/%%r
    if not errorlevel 0 goto somethingbad
    echo final_Dir
    if not errorlevel 0 goto somethingbad
    )
    endlocal
    somethingbad:
        echo "Unexpected error"
```

Note: I am using Windows 10 -pro, 64 bit

Comment: You have `folder` undefined, and perhaps `echo %final_Dir%`.

Comment: @harrymc Sorry. I already added that line im my bat file. I forgot to paste it here.

Comment: I still see `echo final_Dir`.

Comment: windows filesystem uses backslash as a path seperator, not forward slash. Aside from that, variables expanded in code blocks have their value expanded as it was at the start of the code block, `unless`: Delayed expansion is enabled and used, or, CALL is used and `%` expansion is doubled.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off 

pushd "D:\delete_it"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

for /l %%r in (72 1 98)do mkdir %%r && (
       set "_final_dir=!cd!\%%~r"
       <con: echo\!_final_dir!
    ) || (
      echo\Unexpected error^!! & popd
      endlocal & goto :eof
    )

popd & endlocal | <con: echo\Good bye^^!!
```

You don't need to set a variable for your folder, just go to `D:\Delete_it` or use [`pushd`](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) and [`popd`](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)

You can replace all your [`if errorlevel`](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) to operators `&& ==> return 0` and `|| ==> return non 0`

You can replace `goto` (and `:label`) to  `|| (commands in block)`

Comment: Did you mean `>con:` (**to** the screen)? (`echo` doesn't take input)

Comment: @Stephan Thank for your comment,
This is a preference, just as I use `set /p var=string <nul` I like to use `<con:`